# resize issue CListBox inside SDI application with CWnd derived child

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, sdi, clistbox

I am having a problem with the size of the CListBox that is suppose to cover all the client area of the SDi application.

My Main Window looks as shown below:

[image: picture]

As you can clearly see that the list box does not cover the whole client area.
The following is what I am doing in on size of the CWnd derived class:

```
void CLogWnd::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    m_pWndLogList->SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, cx, cy, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
}
```

`CLogWnd` is the main window that fill all the area of the `CMainFrame`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your listbox `LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT` style. Without it, the box wants to have a height that's an exact multiple of a row height.